# nested forms in Rails 4 doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been looking at this for far too long so here goes.

- Trying to do a simple nested form (have done it before *many* times in Rails 3) but I can't seem to get the nest fields to render in HTML.
- As you can see, I'm trying to build 3 'collection components' (my model) with `3.times { @collection.collections_components.build }`. I do get one field but the `3.times` is ignored.
- Seems as though `f.fields_for :collection_components` is ignored. It can be changed to `f.fields_for :xyz` and it executes the same one field.

Following this here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Here's some code:

**collection.rb**

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :collections_components, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :collections_components, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**collections_component.rb**

```
class CollectionsComponent < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :collection
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @collection do |f| %>
  <% if @collection.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@collection.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this collection from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @collection.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :collection_components do |collection_components_form| %>
    <h2>Collection</h2>
    <%= collection_components_form.label :text %>
    <%= collection_components_form.text_field :text %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**collections_controller.rb**

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_collection, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @collections = Collection.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @collection = Collection.new
    3.times { @collection.collections_components.build }
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @collection = Collection.new(collection_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @collection.save
        format.html { redirect_to @collection, notice: 'Collection was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @collection }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @collection.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @collection.update(collection_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @collection, notice: 'Collection was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @collection }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @collection.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @collection.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to collections_url, notice: 'Collection was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_collection
      @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def collection_params
      params.require(:collection).permit(:name, collections_components_attributes: [:text])
    end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean "I get 1 but even that doesn't save." ? You mean only one show up in your HTML form ?

Comment: Also in your strong params, I suspect that you actually wanted `collections_components_attributes: [:text, :id, :_destroy]`. `:id` allows you to identify different attributes, and `_destroy` let you delete. Because I don't really know what you are trying to do with your collection_attributes, I can only guess...

Comment: @CyrilDD, thanks. I'm not too concerned about the strong params as of right now. I'm specifically referring to I'm trying to get 3 collection components text fields (that refer to column 'text') to render. I get one right now but the value doesn't save. Also, when removing the `3.times...` it has no effect.

Comment: @stewart715 Which version of Rails are you using? I added a note on `fields_for`'s change in Rails 4.2.0 to my answer.

Comment: have you tried cocoon gem? https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon there is a railscasts that explains nested forms and it is super easy to achieve the same with cocoon http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=comments

Comment: @DemiMagus I haven't, though I've seen it. I felt like this was a simple enough of a case that I didn't need a gem. I suppose I could give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this could be the problem, you are calling the resource as a singular instead of plural in the _form (at the middle of the name for collection)

```
<%= f.fields_for :collection_components do |collection_components_form| %>
```

instead of this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :collections_components do |collection_components_form| %>
```

Also like i've been using nested_forms before i know that you will need to pass the "id" and only if you are allowing to destroy an attribute a "_destroy" param to the strong_parameters, so it will be good for you to add it

```
def collection_params
  params.require(:collection).permit(:name, collections_components_attributes: [:text])
end
```

So you should have something like this:

```
def collection_params
  params.require(:collection).permit(:name, {collections_components_attributes: [:id, :text, :_destroy]})
end
```

Also i would recommend this [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=comments) for future research and an excelent gem called [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to make nested_forms with ease

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this is really only relevant upon a save. I can't even get the 3 collection component fields to appear in the view.  My  `fields_for :collection_components` doesn't seem to do anything..even when I change it to `fields_for :xyz` (which doesn't exit) it continues just fine with no errors.

Comment: i think this could be the problem, you are calling the resource as a singular instead of plural in the _form (at the middle of the name for collection)

<%= f.fields_for :collection_components do |collection_components_form| %>

instead of this:

<%= f.fields_for :collections_components do |collection_components_form| %>

Comment: Oh jeez! I thought I was going crazy, everything looked perfect. It was. Edit your answer and I'll accept. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to show forms for all the `collections_components`. Change:

```
<%= f.fields_for :collection_components do |collection_components_form| %>
  <h2>Collection</h2>
  <%= collection_components_form.label :text %>
  <%= collection_components_form.text_field :text %>
<% end %>
```

to:

```
<% @collection.collection_components.each do |collections_component| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :collection_components, collections_component do |collection_components_form| %>
    <h2>Collection</h2>
    <%= collection_components_form.hidden_field :id %>
    <%= collection_components_form.label :text %>
    <%= collection_components_form.text_field :text %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The `id`'s hidden field is necessary for updating. Also make sure it's included in the strong parameters.

**EDIT:**

I came across this problem with Rails 4.0.8. The version's document [suggests this solution with `each`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.8/form_helpers.html#using-form-helpers). Rails 4.2.0's document started suggesting only using `fields_for`. I suspect that `fields_for` started handling collection directly in 4.2.0, though I could not find any change log for it.